# Does using the Console in Don't Starve leave a mark?

Tags: dont-starve, cheats

Suppose I want to use the console to spawn an item, fix a bug, or do *whatever*.

Will it leave a "cheater flag" in my save file?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about noting you've used the console on the wiki http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Console/Commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no cheater flag or anything like that. [Console commands](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Console/Commands) are active by default, suggesting it is up to you. The base game is single player so it's not like you're harming other players, there's not really a limit to what you can do so you should be fine.

Normally using console commands or other cheat codes in a game would disable achievements or trophies but there are none in this game so that's not a concern.